# 3d tracking: after render video is shorter than original (same fps and amount of frames)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, video, tracking

I made a 3D track.

When I render the sequence, with the same number of frames (even more) as the original video, and the same fps, I get the video which is shorter than the original. Where I made mistake and how to fix it?

---

Looks like I've just realized what the problem is. In the render settings are the same fps as in the original video, but when I export the rendered sequence in adobe premiere - FPS different! Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: First try converting the source footage to a frame sequence. As blender can have trouble with compressed video files.

Also try including a screen grab or more details of your blend file. Like which tool you are using to composite video and render together.

Comment: @3pointedit Yes, I used the sequence of frames, not video itself . Looks like I've just realized what the problem is. In the render settings are the same fps as in the original video, but when I export the rendered sequence in adobe premiere - FPS different! Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Umm, a frame sequence should have a set number of frames making FPS irrelevant, unless Premier was discarding some frames when exporting?

Comment: @3pointedit the problem is solved! It was in the interpretation of the frame rate of sequence (in the project panel, right click on the clip-modify-interpret footage-assume this frame rate)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is solved! Unrelated to Blender, but on Adobe Premiere. It was in the interpretation of the frame rate of sequence (in the project panel, right click on the clip-modify-interpret footage-assume this frame rate)

[image]

[image]